# ruote and workflow, which is better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We will develop an OA(Office Automation) system in Ruby on Rails, and we need a "Workflow Engine".

I have found two open source projects [route](http://ruote.rubyforge.org/) and [workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) on GitHub.

Which is better?

Comment: Hi, this should ideally be a wiki post, as it is not a programming question.. Pls check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: That's fine. I feel opening up a [community wiki post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki) would benefit you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ruote" is a workflow engine, "workflow" is a state machine library.